# Output is appearing different in the build and in the unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the editor screenshot:

[image]

This is the build screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the stat name appears when I run it in the editor, but when I build it, it does not show in the application. What could be the reason?

The following is the script for the tooltip in the screenshot.

```
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using CharacterStats;
using UnityEngine;

public class StatTooltip : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Text StatNameText;
    [SerializeField] Text StatModifierLabelText;
    [SerializeField] Text StatModifiersText;

    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public void ShowTooltip(CharacterStat stat, string statName)
    {
        StatNameText.text = GetStatTopText(stat, statName);
        StatModifiersText.text = GetStatModifiersText(stat);

        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void HideTooltip()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private string GetStatTopText(CharacterStat stat, string statName)
    {
        sb.Length = 0;
        sb.Append(statName);
        sb.Append(" ");
        sb.Append(stat.Value);
        sb.Append(" (");
        sb.Append(stat.BaseValue);

        if (stat.Value > stat.BaseValue)
            sb.Append("+");

        sb.Append(stat.Value - stat.BaseValue);
        sb.Append(")");
        return sb.ToString();
    }


    private string GetStatModifiersText(CharacterStat stat)
    {
        sb.Length = 0;
        foreach (StatModifier mod in stat.StatModifiers)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
            {
                sb.AppendLine();
            }

            if (mod.Value > 0)
                sb.Append("+");

            sb.Append(mod.Value);

            EquippableItem item = mod.Source as EquippableItem;

            if(item != null)
            {
                sb.Append("  ");
                sb.Append(item.ItemName);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Modifier is not an EquippableItem");
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

The statName shows correctly in the editor but not in the build.

```
using CharacterStats;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class StatDisplay : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    private CharacterStat _stat;
    public CharacterStat Stat
    {
        get { return _stat; }
        set
        {
            _stat = value;
            UpdateStatValue();
        }
    }


    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            nameText.text = _name;
        }
    }

    [SerializeField] Text nameText;
    [SerializeField] Text valueText;
    [SerializeField] StatTooltip tooltip;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        Text[] texts = GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
        nameText = texts[0];
        valueText = texts[1];

        if (tooltip == null)
            tooltip = FindObjectOfType<StatTooltip>();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        tooltip.ShowTooltip(Stat, Name);
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        tooltip.HideTooltip();
    }

    public void UpdateStatValue()
    {
        valueText.text = _stat.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the script which modifies the output?

Comment: Questland? I've played this game :) Also I've noticed that, that equipped sword is different on screenshots

Comment: @AliKanat I've shared the script .

Comment: @Morasiu No, I'm following Kryzarel's tutorial on youtube. Items are different though.

Comment: Did you check the [log files](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) if there is any exception in your build which is not caught. Because the code looks fine to me.

Comment: i checked and found 2 NullReferenceException in the function call statement
`tooltip.ShowTooltip(Stat, Name);` and `tooltip.HideTooltip();` P.S I have posted the entire code above,

Comment: @AliKanat please check the code and see if you can find something.

Answer (score -1):

try to set the "UI Scale Mode" on the "Canvas Scaler" to "Scale with screen Size"!

Edit: its unlikely the fault but i couldnt see the setting on the screenshot and maybe its worth a try if you havent already

Comment: This doesn't really address the question. Since the rest of the UI is scaled correctly I'ld say the odds this has something to do with it are pretty small ;)

Comment: It is set to "Scale with screen Size" only. Thats not whats causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is caused because you are using `OnValidate` for initializing `tooltip`. As far as i know `OnValidate` is used to check the values when it is changed in the Editor. Therefore, it does not work in your build. You should use `Awake` for initialization instead.

Comment: I did that and the issue hasn't been fixed. i think its something to do with the statName and not the tooltip as a whole. since only the statName doesnt appear. But not able to find why.

Comment: Did you move everything in OnValidate to Awake or just tooltip? You have to move everything. Is there any other exception?